# Prioritise og:image

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have a main template which has an opengraph image tag.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.myimage.com/one.png" />
```

I also have a sub template which in the CMS I am using (typo3) inherits all parent  code and adds any specific code for a sub page that I want to put in. eg on this page I want a few special css file which only gets included on this page and its subpages.  This is working fine in most cases but on this particular page I also have a meta tag.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.myimage.com/special.png" />
```

When I lint this on http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint I get both images appearing.  Is it possible to prioritize this?  As far as I can tell it picks either image at random?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is that you can use as many og:image tags as you like, should you require a variety of images, but documentation doesn't seem to state anything on prioritisation. So it appears that the default for multiple og:images is display random for now.

Here's the doc I used to refer to: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/

Sorry I couldn't be much more help.

Comment: thanks I had reviewed that documentation before I thought there may be an undocumented solution but it doesn't look like there is.